# E2E Testing NestJS

Tags: nestjs, supertest

Im new to NestJS and im trying to setup my end to end testing. It does not throw any errors but the request always returns 404.
The test look like this:

```
import { CreateProductDto } from './../src/products/dto/create-product.dto';
import { ProductsModule } from './../src/products/products.module';
import { Product } from './../src/products/entities/product.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { createTypeOrmConfig } from './utils';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

describe('ProductsController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let productRepository: Repository<Product>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const config = createTypeOrmConfig();

    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(config),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Product]),
        ProductsModule,
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    productRepository = moduleFixture.get('ProductRepository');

    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  it('create', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const createProductDto = new CreateProductDto();
    createProductDto.name = 'testname';
    createProductDto.description = 'testdescription';
    createProductDto.price = 120;
    createProductDto.image = 'testimage';

    // Act
    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post(`/api/v1/products`)
      .send(createProductDto);

    // Assert
    expect(response.status).toEqual(201);
  });
});
```

I expected it to returns a 201 response. I tried more routes and same as before.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `@Controller('api/v1/products')` on your `ProductsController`? If not, you don't ever configure the test application to be served from `/api/v1`, you'd need to set the global prefix and enable versioning (assuming you usually do these in your `main.ts`). For a simple fix, remove the `/api/v1` from your `.post()` method.

Comment: The global prefix is set and the endpoint works when the app is running. :(. Thanks

Comment: Versioning is not enabled i just hardcoded v1 on the global prefix. Maybe is that?? Ill try.

Comment: You set the global prefix in the `main.ts`, not in the test application

Comment: Im not on the pc, will check first but you are right.